# How to get multiple related models with as few queries possible

Tags: django, wagtail

I am having some difficulty linking/obtaining data from 3 models all related to one another. I'm thinking i've either designed them incorrectly or I don't fully understand how to work with parental and many-to-many fields.

There are 3 models (*full models shown at end of question*):

- `ClubManager` Where club names are entered
- `ClubTimetables` The timetable, relevant to the `ClubManager`
- `DaysOfTheWeek` Mon-Sun, used by `ClubTimetables`

For which I am trying to retrieve information from all of them: the name of the club, its timetable(s) and for each timetable the days of the week it's linked to. However, I can't seem to do it in a way that doesn't constantly hit the database.

First thing I tried was to get `ClubManager` and `select_related` it's timetable but couldn't figure out how to preselect the `DaysOfTheWeek` it was connected with.

The approach I am trying now is to instead get the `ClubTimetable` and use `select_related` and `prefetch_related` on both the models it's linked with, like so

```py
timetable = ClubTimetables.objects.select_related('attached_to').prefetch_related('weekday')

for t in timetable:
    print(t.attached_to.name)
```

This results in such a query

```py
connection.queries
 
[{'sql': 'SELECT "club_clubtimetables"."id", "club_clubtimetables"."sort_order", "club_clubtimetables"."address_line_1", "club_clubtimetables"."address_line_2", "club_clubtimetables"."address_city", "club_clubtimetables"."address_county", "club_clubtimetables"."address_country", "club_clubtimetables"."map_coord_lat", "club_clubtimetables"."map_coord_lon", "club_clubtimetables"."attached_to_id", "club_clubtimetables"."start_time", "club_clubtimetables"."end_time", "club_clubmanager"."id", "club_clubmanager"."name" FROM "club_clubtimetables" INNER JOIN "club_clubmanager" ON ("club_clubtimetables"."attached_to_id" = "club_clubmanager"."id") ORDER BY "club_clubtimetables"."sort_order" ASC',
  'time': '0.020'},
 {'sql': 'SELECT ("club_clubtimetables_weekday"."clubtimetables_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_clubtimetables_id", "core_daysoftheweek"."id", "core_daysoftheweek"."weekday" FROM "core_daysoftheweek" INNER JOIN "club_clubtimetables_weekday" ON ("core_daysoftheweek"."id" = "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."daysoftheweek_id") WHERE "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."clubtimetables_id" IN (1, 2)',
  'time': '0.002'}]
```

Which looks correct(?)

But, trying to obtain the related weekdays hits the database each time.

```py
for t in timetable:
    for training in t.weekday.values():
        print(training['weekday'])

# Tuesday
# Sunday

In [14]: connection.queries
Out[14]: 
[{'sql': 'SELECT "core_daysoftheweek"."id", "core_daysoftheweek"."weekday" FROM "core_daysoftheweek" INNER JOIN "club_clubtimetables_weekday" ON ("core_daysoftheweek"."id" = "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."daysoftheweek_id") WHERE "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."clubtimetables_id" = 1',
  'time': '0.001'},
 {'sql': 'SELECT "core_daysoftheweek"."id", "core_daysoftheweek"."weekday" FROM "core_daysoftheweek" INNER JOIN "club_clubtimetables_weekday" ON ("core_daysoftheweek"."id" = "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."daysoftheweek_id") WHERE "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."clubtimetables_id" = 2',
  'time': '0.000'}]

# ran again...

for t in timetable:
    for training in t.weekday.values():
        print(training['weekday'])

# Tuesday
# Sunday

In [16]: connection.queries
Out[16]: 
[{'sql': 'SELECT "core_daysoftheweek"."id", "core_daysoftheweek"."weekday" FROM "core_daysoftheweek" INNER JOIN "club_clubtimetables_weekday" ON ("core_daysoftheweek"."id" = "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."daysoftheweek_id") WHERE "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."clubtimetables_id" = 1',
  'time': '0.001'},
 {'sql': 'SELECT "core_daysoftheweek"."id", "core_daysoftheweek"."weekday" FROM "core_daysoftheweek" INNER JOIN "club_clubtimetables_weekday" ON ("core_daysoftheweek"."id" = "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."daysoftheweek_id") WHERE "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."clubtimetables_id" = 2',
  'time': '0.000'},
 {'sql': 'SELECT "core_daysoftheweek"."id", "core_daysoftheweek"."weekday" FROM "core_daysoftheweek" INNER JOIN "club_clubtimetables_weekday" ON ("core_daysoftheweek"."id" = "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."daysoftheweek_id") WHERE "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."clubtimetables_id" = 1',
  'time': '0.001'},
 {'sql': 'SELECT "core_daysoftheweek"."id", "core_daysoftheweek"."weekday" FROM "core_daysoftheweek" INNER JOIN "club_clubtimetables_weekday" ON ("core_daysoftheweek"."id" = "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."daysoftheweek_id") WHERE "club_clubtimetables_weekday"."clubtimetables_id" = 2',
  'time': '0.001'}]
```

Perhaps it is because I'm using `.values()`? But I don't know how else to obtain those values.

My models currently look something like this

```py
# ClubManager

@register_snippet
class ClubManager(ClusterableModel):

    name = models.CharField('Club name',
                            max_length=255,
                            help_text='The name of the club.')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        InlinePanel('club_timetable', heading='Timetable Information')
    ]
```

```py
# ClubTimetables

class ClubTimetables(Orderable, AddressBase):

    attached_to = ParentalKey(
        'club.ClubManager', related_name='club_timetable')

    weekday = models.ManyToManyField(DaysOfTheWeek)

    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    panels = [ ... ] + AddressBase.panels
```

```py
# DaysOfTheWeek

class DaysOfTheWeek(models.Model):

    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.weekday
```

What can I do to fetch all relevant data from these models in one go without repeating db calls?
Or, if I designed these models incorrectly, in what way could build them to use it in the way intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse multiple levels in a `select_related` or `prefetch_related` clause by separating each step with a double underscore:

```
managers = ClubManager.objects.prefetch_related('club_timetable__weekday')
```

Looping over them should then work with no additional queries beyond the initial ones.

```
for manager in managers:
    for timetable in manager.club_timetable.all():
        for weekday in timetable.weekday.all():
            print(weekday)
```

Comment: A very simple and elegant solution. I was not aware that `prefetch_related` would get the `ClubTimetable` as it was not a many-to-many relationship on `ClubManager` or that using an underscore would obtain both the timetable and the weekday records, I've seen chaining mentioned in the Django docs but thought it was to get the last part only e.g. weekdays. Thank you for the help, it's exactly what I needed and very much appreciated!